# Use ratios with algebra

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Sam and Jake live 8 km from each other. Sam skateboards 10 km in the same time as Jake rides his bike 15 km. If they both leave home at the same time and travel towards each other, how far from Jake’s home will they meet?

My Attempt:

J=8-s

3J=2s

I continued from here, but the answer states that these ratios should be flipped around (2J=3S)

why is this?

Comment: What do J and s represent.

Comment: Assuming J his the distance Jake travelled and S is the distance same travelled.  Jake is 3/2 as fast as Sam.  So however far sam travelled Jake travell 3/2 as far.  J = 3/2 s.  Why did you think it was the other way around.

Comment: Jakes distance is 3 times more than something else.  It is *already*  3 times bigger.  You don't multiply the already big thing by 3.

Answer (score 0):

This is a rate problem, as in $d=rt$.  We know that Sam skateboards $10$km in the same time as Jake rides $15$km, or rearranging for time $t=d/r$ and setting the two equal we have
$$
\frac{10}{r_{sam}} = \frac{15}{r_{jake}}
$$
We also know

- The total distance traveled by both is $8$km
- The time traveled for both is equal

giving us 
$$
\frac{8-d}{r_{sam}} = \frac{d}{r_{jake}}
$$
We can solve the first equation for
$$
r_{jake} = \frac{3}{2}r_{sam} 
$$
and plug into the second to have
$$
\frac{8-d}{r_{sam}} = \frac{d}{\frac{3}{2}r_{sam}}
$$
Then
$$
\frac{3}{2}r_{sam}(8-d) = d \ r_{sam}
$$
$$
\frac{3}{2}(8-d) = d
$$
$$
12 - \frac{3}{2}d = d
$$
$$
12 = \frac{5}{2}d
$$
$$
d = 4.8 \text{ km}
$$

Answer (score 0):

First I would find how fast they were going (realizing that no time was given, just that they can travel fixed distances in equal amounts of time).

$$v_{Sam} = \frac{10}{t}\text{ km/hr}$$
$$v_{Jake} = \frac{15}{t}\text{ km/hr}$$
So finding their speeds relative to one another, we have
$$\frac{v_{Jake}}{v_{Sam}} = \frac{\frac{15}{t} \text{ km/hr}}{\frac{10}{t} \text{ km/hr}} = \frac{\frac{15}{t}}{\frac{10}{t}} = \frac{\frac{15}{t}}{\frac{10}{t}}\cdot \frac{\frac{t}{1}}{\frac{t}{1}}=\frac{15}{10} = \frac{3}{2}$$
It was certainly fortunate that the time ($t$) canceled out so nicely.
Summarizing, we have $\color{red}{v_{Sam} = \frac{2}{3}v_{Jake}}$, or $2v_{Jake} = 3v_{Sam}$

We also know that, at the point where they had met, that they had traveled a total of $8$ km (because that is how far apart they live).

Using the fact that $v=\frac{d}{t}\implies d=vt$
We have
$$d_{Jake} + d_{Sam} = 8km$$
$$\frac{d_{Jake} + d_{Sam}}{t} = \frac{8km}{t}$$
$$v_{Jake} + v_{Sam} = \frac{8km}{t}$$
$$v_{Jake} + \color{red}{\frac{2}{3}v_{Jake}} = \frac{8km}{t}$$
$$\frac{5}{3}v_{Jake}  = \frac{8km}{t}$$
$$\frac{5}{3}v_{Jake}\cdot t  = \frac{8km}{t}\cdot t$$
$$\frac{5}{3}d_{Jake}  = 8\text{ km}$$
$$d_{Jake} = \frac{3}{5}\cdot 8 \text{ km} = \frac{24}{5}\text{ km} = 4.8 \text{ km}$$